# Angular: Read json file and inject content to module as dependency

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services, angular-dependency-injection

I have an angular project with lazy loaded modules with **Core** and **shared** modules.
Each module has some **json** configuration files that i need to use their contents in the components with dependency injection.

Which walkthrough is better for this:

**1-** Read **json** files with a file reader service on loading each module and add the mapped object in **DI**.
(Can this happen? dynamically read the json file on module loading and inject the object as dependency?)

**2-** Read **json** file on loading component and use its data.

**3-** Other scenarios?

Comment: Using a provider factory that will return an observable of your config file ?

Comment: @Gilsdav Seems good idea? imagine read file and it is available for whole module. How can i write one?

Comment: The core config will be available on each modules but sub-config will only be available on sub modules. Example: `{ provide: 'MAIN_CONFIG', useFactory: (http: HttpClient) => http.get('...'), deps: [HttpClient] }`. Or if you need to access all configs everywhere, you can use a store that will load configs on demand using `NGXS` for example.